# populate custom spinner from strings xml array

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a `custom spinner` which is replacing my default `spinner` which was populated by hard coded values in my `strings xml`.

I have used my `custom spinner and populated it dynamically in java` but i don't need to do this for this one.

Do i have to populate a list then add it to the spinner in java? and if so how do i populate a list from `strings.xml` array element?

```
    List<String> spinnerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //spinnerList.addAll(R.array.array_spinner);error here, doesnt like this?????????????
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_custom, spinnerList);
    spinnerSports.setAdapter(adapter);

<resources>
    <string-array name="array_custspinner">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //spinnerList.addAll(R.array.array_spinner);error here, doesnt like
>   this?????????????

yes it is correct. addAll is expecting a `Collection` of the same type of your `List`, `String` in your case. But you are providing an `int`, the id of array you want to use. Use

```
List<String> spinnerList = new ArrayList<String>
      (Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_custspinner)));
```

this way you get a modifiable `List<String>` which contains all the strings you defined in you `array_custspinner`